# How to set record limit on a child form then move to next record in parent form when child limit is reached?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I'm creating 2003 access database with 2 tables one called `Advice` and the other `AdviceDetails` with a one-to-many relationship

[image: Table Relationship]

I would like each record for the field `[Advice]![AdviceNum]` PK to be reused in table `[AdviceDetails]![AdviceNum]` FK up to a maximum of 30 times and upon the 31st entry the user will receive a message like: `"You have exceeded the maximum entries for this Advice"`. I also have a field called `ListTotal` in table Advice that I'd like to capture total `AdviceDetails` in relation to each `Advice.`

I've created a user form called `frmAdvice` with a subform called `frmAdviceDetailsSub`

[image: frmAdvice]

Now I want to have the `ListTotal` from the parent form to be updated with the total recordset or record count of the subform each time a new record is added to `frmAdviceDetailsSub.`

I have come up with a code to capture the list total but I have no Idea which event fires each time a new entry is made in the subform:

```
    Dim rst As Object
    Set rst = Me.AdviceDetailsSub.Form.RecordsetClone
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.MoveLast
    On Error GoTo 0
    Me.ListTotal = rst.RecordCount
```

I know my question is a bit complicated but I hope it clear enough to get some answers. Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you so intent on fighting the relational model this way?

Comment: I am just doing it the way I think is the right way if I want to have the parent/child update automatically. If you have a better way please share. I would like to get this done over this weekend so please share. thanks

Comment: Stop worrying about the maximum number of details - that is a red herring and an unnecessary complication.

Comment: I know it may see unnecessary but its a requirement to not have more than 30 per `Advice.` If I could figure out what event is fired after moving between each record in the subform then I think I may be able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much time experimenting and troubleshooting I was able to come up with the following code and it works just fine. So I'm sharing for the benefit of others.

like Parfait I've excluded the error handles for this example.

The first thing is to create an unbound textbox (this case `DetailCount`) in the subform:`frmAdviceDetailsSub` to store the total record count in the recordset

on `frmAdviceDetailsSub` On *Current* Event use:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Dim rst As Object
    Dim RecSum As Integer    'Stores the sum of records in the recordset (yes, weird sounding variable lol)

    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    rst.MoveLast        
    RecSum = rst.RecordCount

    'Because a new record will read (1 of 0) I had to make the following twist to get 1 of 1
    If Me.NewRecord Then
        Me.DetailCount = Me.CurrentRecord & " of " & (RecSum + 1)     'eg. 1 of 1
        If (RecSum + 1) > 30 Then
            MsgBox "You reached the maximum entries for this Advice", vbOKOnly, "Notice"
            Me.AllowAdditions = False    'PS. no need to undo just prevent addition as this test is before entry.
        End If
    Else
        Me.AllowAdditions = True
        Me.DetailCount = Me.CurrentRecord & " of " & RecSum
    End If

    If RecSum > 0 Then
        Me.Parent.ListTotal = RecSum    'to prevent this line from generating errors make the subform unbound then use the main form's on load event to assign it's recordsource. (child forms are loaded before parent)
    End If
    Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

For `frmAdvice` On *Load* event use:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.AdviceDetailsSub.SourceObject = "AdviceDetailsSub"
End Sub
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

In the **AfterInsert** event of the subform, enter the code you specified (I left out the error handles). However, you cannot use the relative reference (Me) alias since you are on the subform and must make an absolute reference to main form.

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()    
    Dim rst As Object
    Set rst = Forms!frmAdvice!AdviceDetailsSub.Form.RecordsetClone    
    rst.MoveLast
    rst.MoveFirst

    Forms!frmAdvice!ListTotal = rst.RecordCount
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

And in the **BeforeUpdate** event of the subform, check to see if ListTotal reached 30. If it did, it sends the message to user about maximum level allowed and cancels the auto save of the current record. The Undo clears any changes the user may have entered.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
   If Forms!frmAdvice!ListBox >= 30 Then
      Msgbox "You have exceeded the maximum entries for this Advice.", vbInformation, "Maximum limit"
      Cancel = True
      Me.Undo
   End If
End Sub
```